# R how to get binary representation of files

Tags: r, binary

I need to build a classifier which will receive a file as input and then it needs to decide type of that file...For example valid classifications could be an image file, a movie file, a sound file, a text file with character data, a text file with numeric data

I am thinking of looking at the binary representation of files and then building a machine learning algorithm.

Is there a R package which can provide me binary representation of a file once I provide the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a package necessarily. You can open a file in binary read mode and use `readBin` to pull out the data how ever you like. A shortened version from  the `?readBin` help page

```
zz <- file("testbin", "wb")
writeBin(1:10, zz)
writeBin(pi, zz, endian = "swap")
writeBin(pi, zz, size = 4)
writeBin(pi+3i, zz)
writeBin("A test of a connection", zz)
z <- paste("A very long string", 1:100, collapse = " + ")
writeBin(z, zz)
close(zz)

zz <- file("testbin", "rb")
readBin(zz, integer(), 4)
readBin(zz, integer(), 6)
readBin(zz, numeric(), 1, endian = "swap")
readBin(zz, numeric(), size = 4)
readBin(zz, complex(), 1)
readBin(zz, character(), 1)
z2 <- readBin(zz, character(), 1)
close(zz)
unlink("testbin")
```

Once you look at a file by just it's bytes, you can interpret those bytes how ever you would like.